# Is it possible to include external files when using Jade’s :markdown filter?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, markdown, pug

I'm building an Express.js Node app and using Jade templates. Jade provides a `:markdown` filter which enables embedding Markdown code inside Jade:

```
h1 This is Jade
:markdown
  ## And this is Markdown
h3 Back in Jade
```

(Note: In order to use this filter you have to npm install a Markdown engine, e.g. `npm install marked --save`. You don't have to `require()` this module within your Express app, but it has to be installed.)

So, embedding Markdown within Jade works fine. However, I would like to keep my Markdown in separate files and include them in Jade templates dynamically. I've tried this and it does not work:

```
:markdown
  include ../path/to/markdown/file.md
```

The `include` command is treated as source code instead of being interpreted as a command. Is it possible to inject Markdown from external files within the `:markdown` filter?

**Please don't provide workarounds!** I know how to work around this issue. I want to know if the `:markdown` filter is compatible with external Markdown files.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can include markdown files using the :md filter modifier.

eg.

```
html
  body
    include:md ../path/to/markdown/file.md
```

Language Reference: https://pugjs.org/language/includes.html#including-filtered-text

Comment: Tested and works. Not mentioned in the language reference ಠ_ಠ

Comment: I'm updating the language reference over the next couple of days to keep up with the 1.0.0 release.  Pull requests are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

the `:md` modifier does not work for me either, but this works:

```
html
  body

    // works:

    include file.md

    //- does not work:

    include:markdown file.md
    include:md file.md
```

I am using docpad with the [HTML5 Boilerplate](https://github.com/jh3y/html5-boilerplate-jade-less-livereload.docpad/blob/master/src/files/README.md) template.

You also should consider the problem of no auto-generation of including `*.html.jade` files of such includes:

[How to auto-generate html from jade file when only included markdown file has changed in livereload development environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25591806/how-to-auto-generate-html-from-jade-file-when-only-included-markdown-file-has-ch)

Comment: I am using docpad 6.53.4, docpad-plugin-jade 2.6.2, markdown 0.5.0 and html5-boilerplate-less-jade-livereload.docpad 0.1.0

Comment: **after upgrading to docpad 6.69.1, docpad-plugin-jade 2.8.0, docpad-plugin-marked 2.2.1 the `include:md` variant works and `include file.md` not anymore**

Answer (score 0):

First, run this command:

```
npm install marked --save
```

Then, do this:

```
include:md ../path/to/markdown/file.md
```