# How to auto-generate html from jade file when only included markdown file has changed in livereload development environment?

Tags: pug, markdown, docpad

So I've got a file like this:

```
# index.html.jade
p Test
include content.md
```

So **if I change the content of `content.md` `out/index.html` is not regenerated** (because the `index.html.jade` file itself of course has not changed).
(I am using *livereload* - [in the HTML 5 Boilerplate](https://github.com/jh3y/html5-boilerplate-jade-less-livereload.docpad/blob/master/src/files/README.md) docpad template - and the so the browser does not refresh on a valid change :-( )

On the other hand the final `out/index.html` file of the previous and current version (after the `content.md` change) are different (most likely on visible changes).

I see ways how this could/should be treated (maybe it is already possible):

- the (jade) change-checking should also consider dependent files that may influence the output (e.g. `include`d files) and thus regenerate the including files if the included ones changed
- workarounds (if the above should be tricky within the framework):

  - option to regenerate all or some files on changes to certain other ones (or at least a re-generation of all files for ease of development)

    - if the project is not too big this should be no big deal

Comment: I am using docpad 6.53.4, docpad-plugin-jade 2.6.2, markdown 0.5.0 and html5-boilerplate-less-jade-livereload.docpad 0.1.0. And maybe its worth mentioning that this kind of include (which works for me) is mentioned elsewhere with different syntax which didn't work for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25591846/1915920

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ha ... easy built-in solution discovered: **adding `referencesOthers: true` in the meta data area** does it :-)

```
---
title: my cool page
layout: default
referencesOthers: true
---
include some.markdown.file.md
```

More details [here](http://docpad.org/docs/meta-data).